# Set up Sails 0.10.x fixtures with barrels, but none are in the database

Tags: testing, sails.js, fixtures

Starting from [this example](https://github.com/bredikhin/sailsjs-mocha-testing-barrels-fixtures-example/blob/master/test/index.js) (using Sails 0.9.x) from the Barrels author himself with slight modification based on in [Barrels' repo](https://github.com/bredikhin/barrels/blob/master/test/index.test.js) (using Sails 0.10.x) and my project setup, here's my configuration:

`<Project>/test/specHelper.js` (which is the test bootstrap):

```
'use strict';

var Sails   = require('sails')
  , Barrels = require('barrels')
  , barrels, fixtures;

before(function(done) {
  Sails.lift(
    {
      // Configuration for testing
      environment: 'test',
      log: {
        level: 'error'
      },
      connections: {
        test: {
          adapter: 'sails-memory'
        }
      },
      models: {
        connection: 'test'
      },
      port: 98765
    },

    function(err, sails) {
      if (err)
        return done(err);

      // Load fixtures
      barrels   = new Barrels(process.cwd() + '/tests/fixtures');
      fixtures  = barrels.data;
      barrels.populate(function(err) {
        done(err, sails);
      });

    }
  );
});

after(function(done) {
  // Clear fixtures, etc.
  Sails.lower(done);
});
```

and here's a spec file `<Project>/tests/EntitySpec.js`

```
var chai    = require('chai');
  , expect  = chai.expect;

describe('Entity', function() {

  describe('class methods', function() {

    describe('#a_method', function() {

      it('does something', function(done) {
        Entity.find().then(function(results) {
          console.log('in database', results);
          done();
        }).catch(done);

      });
    });
  });
});
```

But the test database is empty. Running `barrels.populate` in the spec file doesn't solve this (though specs doesn't throw any error). I'm open for other fixture solution for Sails.js. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The example you're referring to](https://github.com/bredikhin/sailsjs-mocha-testing-barrels-fixtures-example) was updated for the new `Barrels` API and it's passing the tests.

Otherwise, check if the objects are in the `fixtures` variable: if it's empty, make sure you're providing the correct path to the JSON files (you're passing `process.cwd() + '/tests/fixtures'`, but your helper is in `<Project>/test/specHelper.js`, also, you have `<Project>/tests/EntitySpec.js`; is it `test` or `tests`?).

If the `fixtures` are present, make sure you're passing the correct configuration to `Sails.lift` and your connection is configured correctly (see the mentioned example for details).

Comment: Thanks for answering. Understand it was updated. I also stated that is also based on the updated one.

The `fixtures` variable is not empty so the setup path is correct (it is in `tests`). 

As for `Sails.lift` configuration, I follow the same config as the [Barrels's test setup](https://github.com/bredikhin/barrels/blob/master/test/index.test.js)

Comment: I updated the example just yesterday, after reading your question, so yours couldn't be based on the updated one. Check it out. Also, make sure you're using Waterline's promise API properly: try using `exec` instead of `then` (http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/Models.html?q=using-models).